# Updating geometry of point using OGR in Python?

Tags: python, ogr

I need to change the coordinates (geometry) of some points in a shapefile. I can't find the good method.

```
if ( zone[best_y, best_x] >= ( nb_pixel_area - toler) ) and ( zone[best_y, best_x] <= ( nb_pixel_area + toler) ):
        print('======= station deplacee')
        new_x = (( pix_x + best_x ) * hres ) + georef[0]
        new_y = (( pix_y + best_y ) * abs(hres) ) + georef[3]
        wkt   = "POINT(%f %f)" %  (new_x , new_y)
        point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
        gauge.SetGeometryDirectly(point)
```

I was also not able to use the setX() and setY().

Has someone already done that action?

Comment: I'm not working under Qgis. Anyway, I've found the problem. This statement was missing :            reloc_lyr.SetFeature(gauge)

Comment: If you are able to answer your own question then please expand your comment into a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this snippet:

[**Modify Features**](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html)

> It is possible to either change feature’s geometry or to change some
>   attributes. The following example first changes values of attributes
>   with index 0 and 1, then it changes the feature’s geometry

```
fid = 100   # ID of the feature we will modify

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues:
  attrs = { 0 : "hello", 1 : 123 }
  layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeGeometries:
  geom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(111,222))
  layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ fid : geom })
```